# Array to JSON Array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, mongodb, alamofire

I have two array of Integers and I like to send it to my mongodb database. When I send it to database in Alamofire as paramter and in code data_array 1 and 2 refers to Int arrays.

```
  let parameters_post: Parameters = [
        "sensor_id": "ecg_raw",
        "member_id": "58d3f509e48f4ca90dd218e4",
        "esignal": "3.5V",
        "ts": "emre",
        "value1" : data_array1,
        "value2" : data_array2
    ]

     Alamofire.request("https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/mysignal/collections/Cecgraw?apiKey=2ABdhQTy1GAWiwfvsKfJyeZVfrHeloQI", method: .post, parameters: parameters_post,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseData{ response in
        print(response.request)
        print(response.response)
        print(response.result)
    }
```

However, It is seen as like this in mongodb. I think which is incorrect;

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "58f9d0e7c2ef162ad3000cb6"
},
"sensor_id": "ecg_raw",
"member_id": "58d3f509e48f4ca90dd218e4",
"value2": [
    [
        240,
        279,
        555,
        547,
        504
    ]
],
"value1": [
    [
        135,
        91,
        101,
        115,
        106
    ]
],
"esignal": "3.5V",
"ts": "emre"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As per you said you want to send value for key `value` as `[(Int, Int)]`. But actually you are sending as `[[(Int, Int)]]`, which means `array of array of tuples`(Hope you need to send as `array of tuples`).

Try to send list below,

```
let parameters_post: Parameters = [
    "sensor_id": "ecg_raw",
    "member_id": "58d3f509e48f4ca90dd218e4",
    "esignal": "3.5V",
    "ts": "emre",
    "value" : data_array
]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I change the structure. Can you please check the new one? I had two integer values and I decided to store them on different arrays. But still can't write it to database.

Comment: What error are you facing? What is the sample JSON?

Comment: Actually, I don't know exactly. As I searched, In JSON array should be like with "{" bracelet. But In my output, there is only square bracelet.

Comment: Okay. Could you please tell what error you are facing?

Comment: I'm not facing with anyproblem now. I mean I can store the values as I give the example but I'm not sure If it is an array or not and can I fetch it probably.

Comment: I have debugged your api. Your response JSON is not valid one. Please make sure your JSON is valid and then try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142270/discussion-between-karthick-and-emre-onder).